# What's VP6, VP7 Decoder settings?

Tags: windows-7, video

See the screenshot below. What do VP6 and VP7 stand for?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.videsignline.com/208808468?printableArticle=true

> This article is an introduction
>   to On2's most recent TrueMotion codec:
>   VP7.
>
> A video compressor's goal is simple:
>   take raw video data in, and output a
>   much smaller amount of compressed
>   data. A decompresser...

Looks like you have On2's VP7 installed chief.